# Read/write variables which are not in DBs using S7.Net library

Tags: c#, plc, tia-portal

I'm currently programming an app in C#, I have to make a connection with a PLC through TIA Portal.
I'm using S7.Net library which allows the connection and the data exchange.

However, every videos I've watched read and write variables from DBs :

```cs
ushort val = 40000;
plc.Write("DB1.DBW0", val);
```

but I'm not using DBs, only PLC tags and this doesn't work :

```cs
bool val = true;
plc.Write("I0.0", val);
```

I don't really know if it is possible, or if it exists another library allowing it.

Comment: You should read the Siemens documentation : https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/153/109739153/att_895955/v1/s7-plcsim_advanced_function_manual_en-US_en-US.pdf?force_isolation=true

Comment: PLCSim Advanced is for virtual controller

Comment: The language is still the same as well as the module types.

Comment: I need to create an instance on PLCSim advanced to do I/O data exchange. How can i make an instance with a real PLC

Comment: Do you mean to connected to an instance?  See page 105.

Comment: No, i already know how to connect to an instance but on PLCSim Adv. it creates a virtual PLC. I want to connect myself to a real PLC, but i don't know if it possible through PLCSim Adv.

Comment: It is all done through the connection string.  See : http://www.plcdev.com/connecting_s7_plc?force_isolation=true